# Idea for better performance in development environment Web Logic remote?

Tags: java, weblogic

I would like to ask for help and guidance, about the problem and the idea I had, open to suggestions.

I'm working on a project where the application is in weblogic and there are several modules.

In the dev team, everyone has ecplise and weblogic localhost on their machine to run the application and carry out maintenance or improvement in the code.

The problem is that in some modules, because they are more complex and very large, we have a very long delay for each new build, sometimes around 30 min, maybe for more experienced developers who are already familiar with the code, it is simpler,

More in my case as just a junior developer we often make changes to then test the change in the application and from republish to republish if it goes a few hours a day.

In this case, I thought if you could not migrate the local environment from weblogic to TOMCAT, however, as an application has 12 modules, taking all this to TOMCAT was very unfeasible because there was a need for one more running.

So as we have a certain resource available on azure I had the idea of ​​running a container in docker with weblogic and performing the remote debug on weblogic and publish too, so the performance would be better and on the local machine I would run ecplise.

This idea of ​​running weblogic via docker and leaving ecplise only to connect to weblogic would it be possible to really perform republish and debug with quality?.

Ecplise: Photon WebLogic: 12.2.1.4.0 Java:7

Comment: What causes the 30min delay for each new build?  Is the build done locally (using mvn?) or on a CI server? If it's done locally, is it unit tests that are taking so long?  A local weblogic server really should be the fastest option for a developer to change and test code, so I would suggest identifying what is causing the delay and addressing that.  You should still also have a common DEV server where all changes are deployed to as well.

Comment: So it's all locally the complication is done locally with mvn.

The delay happens when weblogic is in publish, especially when a module fails and it automatically tries to redeploy.

Comment: Is your publish done from eclipse or mvn?  How much memory is your local weblogic server configured to have (-Xmx setting)?

Comment: Publish is done by ecplise and weblogic is configured to use 12gb of ram

Comment: I have seen weblogic deploys take ages when memory is low and after several deploys from eclipse, which is fixed by a weblogic reboot.  You do have alot of memory for your local server though so that shouldn't be an issue.  What cuases a module publish to fail and eclipse to automatically retry?  When a publish fails in my eclipse it doesn't auto retry.